# C2DM - Cloud to Device Messaging

Tags: android-c2dm

C2DM - Cloud to Device Messaging :
Can I use it for "device to device" comunication without a server?

Answer (score 0):

No, you fundamentally need a server.  Also, C2DM has been replaced with GCM as of yesterday.  [Read more here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html) about the architecture of GCM, that may help you to understand how it works and why an application server is integral.